# Adding business days to python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Wonking on pandas dataframes -

I have a date format like this: `datetime64[ns]` and a column with a `int64` format.

the dataframe looks like this:

```
           date    days        
0    2019-07-04       1 
1    2019-10-17       1 
2    2019-10-17       2
```

i want to use this function to add n business days:

```
def add_business_days(from_date,ndays):
    business_days_to_add = abs(ndays)
    current_date = from_date
    sign = ndays/abs(ndays)
    while business_days_to_add > 0:
        current_date += datetime.timedelta(sign * 1)
        weekday = current_date.weekday()
        if weekday >= 5: # sunday = 6
            continue
        business_days_to_add -= 1
    return current_date
```

But i somehow get this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Could you help on that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pandas` has an implemented support for business days. I am not absolutely sure what your output is supposed to like like (since you did not include an expected output, could you please add it?), but I guess this is what you want:

```
pd.to_datetime(from_date) + pd.offsets.BDay(ndays)
```

Assuming your dataframe looks like this:

```
dates = [pd.to_datetime('2019-07-04'), pd.to_datetime('2019-10-17'), pd.to_datetime('2019-10-17')]
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'date': dates, 'days': [1, 1, 2]})
```

The conversion to a timestamp with `pd.to_datetime()` can be omitted.

Comment: `TypeError: 'n' argument must be an integer, got <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`

Comment: Sorry, I see only edit 5 minutes after my solution and it was same, so then you can add to answer - use another solution, not copy it. Also now it is bad - your wrong answer is accepted :(

Comment: Yeah, I edited the bold reference to your answer several times to try to make it clear that that part of the answer was coming from you. As I said: It was ment as a commendation and not as an offense! Furthermore my solution was going to like nearly exactly like your answer. Just look at what I posted before you. It is quite much exactly the return of your function. So I could also complain that you copied it and just made it into a function. But imho that'd be goofy, since it is the most "straight-forward" solution using pandas and thus it is highly likely that the code is mostly congruent.

Comment: So imho complaining that I took your answer and editing my post is not the right way. I could have said exactly the same about your function return line... And why is it bad and what is bad? Neither is my answer wrong (except for a singular typo), nor is it bad.

Comment: yop, OK, your solution is not bad, only not working for data. Here is necessary apply.

Comment: Well, the question still has no expected output or an example how the given function is supposed to be executed (and with which arguments). Thus my initial answer was supposed to be as general as possible to cover all use cases (f.i. what if the col `days` was not supposed to be used as the offset and instead a constant offset was intended?). My edit (starting with "Assuming your dataframe looks like...") was then supposed to cover the most likely case, but at this point you were faster.

Comment: hmmm, so you have solution before me, so is not problem explain it? If you know is necessary use `apply`, why not use in your first solution? It is not clear for me and before this I think answer was copied. But maybe I am wrong...

Answer (score 1):

Use lambda function with [`offsets.BDay`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.BDay.html):

```
def add_business_days(from_date,ndays):
    return from_date + pd.offsets.BDay(ndays)

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['new'] = df.apply(lambda x: add_business_days(x['date'], x['days']), axis=1)
```

Or:

```
df['new'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['date'] +  pd.offsets.BDay(x['days']), axis=1)
```

---

```
print (df)
        date  days        new
0 2019-07-04     1 2019-07-05
1 2019-10-17     1 2019-10-18
2 2019-10-17     2 2019-10-21
```